# Join query resultset with another table

Tags: sql-server, join, hive

I have 3 tables Sourcetable,Mappingtable,Destinationtable in Hive.

Here I am joining first two tables based on join condition. But when trying to perform Right join with third table I am facing issues. Criterias to be followed in 'Destination table'.

1. Should fetch only March 5th data and should contain matching rows from sourcetables as well the remaining rows from destination table.
   Query I have used is given below. Left join works correctly. But when I try to join Destination table it is not correct.

I have provided table relations and the output to be achieved in outputtable.
Any sort of guidance is appreciated.

```
(select a.Account as Accounts, a.customer as customers,a.productci,b.product_cr as Productcr,sum(a.cost)/sum(a.quantity) as perprice,
from sourcetable a 
LEFT join mappingtable b on( a.productci = b.product_ci ) where (a.createddate >= '2018-03-01' and a.createddate < '2018-03-06') 
GROUP BY a.customer,a.Account,a.productci,b.product_cr order by a.Account,a.customer) AS TEST
RIGHT JOIN destinationtable Temp on(TEST.Productcr=Temp.productgr) where temp.createddate='2018-03-05'
GROUP BY temp.customer,temp.Account,temp.productgr
```

Table details are shown below

SOURCETABLE

```
Account,customer,productci,quantity,cost,Createddate
A01,S01,100,3000,120000,3/5/2018
A02,S02,140,4000,180000,3/4/2018
```

Mappingtable

```
product_ci,product_cr,proddesc
100,4991089,Product1
140,4991090,Product2
150,4991091,Product3
120,4991092,Product4
```

Destination table

```
Account,customer,productgr,volume,placeid,Createddate
A01,S01,4991089,1890000,P01,3/5/2018
A02,S02,4991090,1890001,P02,3/5/2018
A03,S03,4991091,1890002,P03,3/5/2018
A04,S04,4991092,1890003,P04,3/5/2018
A05,S05,4991093,1890004,P05,3/5/2018
```

Output:Result

```
Account,customer,productgr,volume,Perprice,placeid
A01,S01,4991089,1890000,40,P01
A02,S02,4991090,1890001,45,P02
A03,S03,4991091,1890002,285.1002865,P03
A04,S04,4991092,1890003,30,P04
A05,S05,4991093,1890004,1170.113097,P05
```

Comment: I cannot convert the png tables into XLS or db tables.  Please upload these as CSV text files so that I can reproduce the results and fix the SQL.

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text, including tables & ERDs. Use images only to augment text. Textual content of images/links cannot be searched for or copied & pasted. Please give a [mcve]. That includes a clear description of what you want your query to do. Your question is not clear about that.

Comment: Have you tried converting date as `Convert(varchar,Your_date_col,112)` and replace date as `20180305` or `YearMonthDate`?

Comment: Actual date format is YYY-MM-DD as I have used in the sample query.Table schema  provided above is just for understanding the relation between fields.